# Are there any problems running ASP.NET applications on Microsoft Small Business Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-7, windows-server-2008, small-business-server

I am looking at installing my ASP.NET app on my client's Microsoft Small Business Server Premium Edition, but I've never used it as a platform. Are there any limitations or restrictions I need to be aware of?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint is one of the pillars of SBS, which is largely an ASP.NET application, so I can't imagine there are any restrictions in using ASP.NET on SBS.

Comment: Does that mean that Sharepoint takes over IIS in SBS? Can you run other public web apps alongside it? (I don't think you can under normal Sharepoint installs).